# HTML5 / JavaScript camera blurry, only on front facing camera, only on my app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have built a visitor management system and have recently swapped to a surface device as the driver. The html5 webcam stream is showing as blurry / out of focus on the front facing camera. If I swap to the rear camera however it is fine. And if i use the front facing camera on another public site that uses another webcam feature, it works absolutely fine.

Here is a capture of the camera element, it looks like some form of deliberate blurring as appose to the camera just being bad...
https://ibb.co/Dzf67nC/

I have tried scanning through the code and cannot find anything that scales the camera stream at all that may cause bluring or focus changing

Below is my photo.js file that provides the stream to my visitor sign in page and also handles the capturing of screenshots.

```
// References to all the element we will need.
var video = document.querySelector('#camera-stream'),
    image = document.querySelector('#snap'),
    my_photo = document.querySelector('#my-photo'),
    container = document.querySelector('.camera-container'),
    //start_camera = document.querySelector('#start-camera'),
    controls = document.querySelector('.controls'),
    take_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#take-photo'),
    delete_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#delete-photo'),
    download_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#download-photo'),
    imgeurl = document.querySelector('#imagesource'),
    open_camera = document.querySelector('#open-camera'),
    error_message = document.querySelector('#error-message');


// The getUserMedia interface is used for handling camera input.
// Some browsers need a prefix so here we're covering all the options
navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
                      navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                      navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                      navigator.msGetUserMedia);



// Mobile browsers cannot play video without user input,
// so here we're using a button to start it manually.

open_camera.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if($('#my-photo').attr('src') == '') { 

    e.preventDefault();
    container.classList.add("visible");
    // Start video playback manually.
    //video.play();
    //showVideo();

    if(!navigator.getMedia){
      displayErrorMessage("Your browser doesn't have support for the navigator.getUserMedia interface.");
    }
    else{

      // Request the camera.
      navigator.getMedia(
        {
          video: true
        },
        // Success Callback
        function(stream){

          // Create an object URL for the video stream and
          // set it as src of our HTLM video element.
          video.srcObject=stream;

          // Play the video element to start the stream.
          video.play();
          video.onplay = function() {
            showVideo();
          };
        },
        // Error Callback
        function(err){
          displayErrorMessage("There was an error with accessing the camera stream: " + err.name, err);
        }
      );

    }
  }

});

open_camera.click();

take_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){

 e.preventDefault();

 var count=4;
 var counter=setInterval(timer, 500); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
 $('.countdown-container').addClass('visible');
 function timer(){
     count=count-1;
     if (count <= 0)
     {
      $('.countdown-number').html('<i class="far fa-smile"></i>');
       clearInterval(counter);
       //counter ended, do something here
       return;
  }
  $('.countdown-number').text(count);
 //Do code for showing the number of seconds here
 }

 setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('.countdown-container').removeClass('visible');
  $('.countdown-number').text('Get Ready');
},2500);

  setTimeout(function(){ 

      video.pause(snap);
      var snap = takeSnapshot();
        // Show image. 
      image.setAttribute('src', snap);
      imgeurl.value = snap;
      image.classList.add("visible");
      //tumbnail image
      my_photo.setAttribute('src', snap);
      my_photo.value = snap;

      // Enable delete and save buttons
      delete_photo_btn.classList.remove("disabled");
      download_photo_btn.classList.remove("disabled");
      take_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");

  },3000);

  // Set the href attribute of the download button to the snap url.


  // Pause video playback of stream.


});

delete_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){

  e.preventDefault();

  // Hide image.
  image.setAttribute('src', "");
  image.classList.remove("visible");
  my_photo.setAttribute('src', "");

  // Disable delete and save buttons
  delete_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");
  download_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");
  take_photo_btn.classList.remove("disabled");

  // Resume playback of stream.
  video.play();

});

function showVideo(){
  // Display the video stream and the controls.
  //hideUI();
  video.classList.add("visible");
  controls.classList.add("visible");
}

function takeSnapshot(){
  // Here we're using a trick that involves a hidden canvas element.  

  var hidden_canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
      context = hidden_canvas.getContext('2d');
  var width = video.videoWidth,
      height = video.videoHeight;
  if (width && height) {

    // Setup a canvas with the same dimensions as the video.
    hidden_canvas.width = width;
    hidden_canvas.height = height;

    // Make a copy of the current frame in the video on the canvas.
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

    // Turn the canvas image into a dataURL that can be used as a src for our photo.
    return hidden_canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  }
}

download_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  container.classList.remove("visible");
  my_photo.classList.add("visible");

});

function displayErrorMessage(error_msg, error){
  error = error || "";
  if(error){
    console.log(error);
  }

  error_message.innerText = error_msg;

  hideUI();
  error_message.classList.add("visible");
}

function hideUI(){
  // Helper function for clearing the app UI.
  controls.classList.remove("visible");
  //start_camera.classList.remove("visible");
  video.classList.remove("visible");
  snap.classList.remove("visible");
  error_message.classList.remove("visible");
}
```

The camera should be a lot crisper than it is. No errors or anything in the console.

Comment: This is because of some devices not having autofocus for `get​User​Media()
` on the front-facing camera. whats the device are you using?

Comment: I'm using the front-facing camera on the Microsoft Surface Go.

Comment: then, unfortunately, you need to join [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/all/surface-pro-4s-front-webcam-blurry-with-webrtc/e0e6b2e0-04ce-4d34-98e9-c962ee2e1e9b?page=3) bandwagon, my friend